# Directive on <input> not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select element:

```
<select ng-model="user" data-ng-options="user.Forename + ' ' + user.Surname for user in allusers"></select>
```

And after this, I have 3 inputs:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ user.Surname }}" />
<input type="text" value="{{ user.Forename }}" />
<input data-convert-json-date data-jsondate="{{ user.DOB }}" />
```

The third input has a directive applied to convert a unix-style date to a human readable date.

```
myApp.directive('convertJsonDate', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        var JSONdate = attrs.jsondate;
        var formattedDate = new Date(parseInt(JSONdate.substr(6))); 
        el.val(formattedDate.format("dd/mm/yyyy"));
     }
  }
});
```

However, the third input remains blank even though the first two inputs are updated as the select changes.

Any ideas why this directive isnt working?

Comment: Is the directive being called if you set a breakpoint in your browser's debugger?

Comment: Only when the wep app starts up. If i keep changing the selected item from select element, the breakpoint doesnt get hit on change.

Comment: So you put your breakpoint in the link method?

Comment: yes on the line: var JSONdate = attrs.jsondate;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is beause you are not watching for changes, not because of input tag...

You need to change your code like following:

```
myApp.directive('convertJsonDate', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    scope:{
        jsondate: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('jsondate', function(JSONdate){
            var formattedDate = new Date(parseInt(JSONdate.substr(6))); 
            el.val(formattedDate.format("dd/mm/yyyy"));
        })
     }
  }
});
```

As suggested by @ryeballar instead of isolated scope and watch on it, you can use `attrs.$observe()`, and it would be more efficient:

```
attrs.$observe('jsondate', function (JSONdate) {
    var formattedDate = new Date(parseInt(JSONdate.substr(6))); 
    el.val(formattedDate.format("dd/mm/yyyy"));
});
```

Comment: Now you've said it, it's obvious. I had no mechanism to fire the change when the scope changed. I have put the watch in and it now works. Many thanks to you and Dean Ward for your help.

Comment: Spot on, I should stop trying to answer questions on my phone, takes a long time to write code :)

Comment: I feel that the watcher and the scope isolation is an overkill in this context. You may use the `attrs.$observe()` to get the updated values of the interpolated value.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.$observe()` method of the `attr` parameter of the linking function to get what you want, no need to isolate the scope itself and create a watcher for it.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="{{ user.Surname }}" />
<input type="text" value="{{ user.Forename }}" />
<input data-convert-json-date="{{ user.DOB }}" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
myApp.directive('convertJsonDate', function () {
   return function(scope, elem, attr) {
     attr.$observe('convertJsonDate', function(JSONdate) {
        var formattedDate = new Date(parseInt(JSONdate.substr(6))); 
        elem.val(formattedDate.format("dd/mm/yyyy"));
     });
   };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So I think your directive is not firing because there is no binding between the attribute and your directive...

Two things you could do here...

1) Write a filter instead and use ng-model to bind to your property. E.g. Ng-model='user.DOB | jsondate'. See the [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).

2) Change your directive to use scope isolation and bind to your property. E.g.

```
myApp.directive('convertJsonDate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
        jsondate: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('jsondate', function(JSONdate){
            var formattedDate = new Date(parseInt(JSONdate.substr(6))); 
            el.val(formattedDate.format("dd/mm/yyyy"));
        })
    }
  }
});
```

Edit: @Bogdan Savluk beat me to it :)